# Are there specific settings I need to use when preparing images for use with custom UITabBarItem's?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm using free images off of iconfinder and they work fine. However I couldn't find a specific image so had to find the image elsewhere.

Anyway the image was an incorrect size so I resized it in photoshop.

I added the image to the images.xcassets folder and used the image for the uibarbuttonitem. 
The image has come out as a grey square box.
Highlighting works but all I see is a box.

Am I missing something here?

Would appreciate some help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change a setting in photoshop. When saving the photo I had to make sure interlanced was chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is a PNG. What is the size of the image you are using?

[Apple's iOS HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Comment: Image is PNG and 32x32